# How to apply changes to global variable to other variable with the same name inside functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a global variable named "id". The variable changes whenever I select another input. But somehow the other functions which have "id" do not reflect the current value changed using live.

```
// Start Ready
$j(document).ready(function() {  

var id;

$j("input").live('click', function(haha){
    id = document.activeElement.id;
    console.log(id);
});

// Live Search
// On Search Submit and Get Results
function search() {
    var query_value = $('input#' + id).val();
    $j('b#search-string').text(query_value);
    if(query_value !== ''){
        $j.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "clientsearch.php",
            data: { query: query_value },
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("ul#client-result").html(html);
            }
        });
    }return false;    
}

$j("input#" + id).live("keyup", function(e) {
    // Set Timeout
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));

    // Set Search String
    var search_string = $(this).val();

    // Do Search
    if (search_string == '') {
        $j("ul#client-result").fadeOut();
    }else{
        $j("ul#client-result").fadeIn();
        $j(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 100));
    };
});

});
```

Comment: `$j("input#" + id).live(...` won't work as expected, because the event listener is only attached once.

Comment: change `$j("input#" + id).live("keyup", function(e) {` to `$j("input" ).live("keyup", function(e) {` and then your code should work as expected.

Comment: *'I have a global variable named "id".'* - No you don't. The only `id` variable in the code shown is local to the document ready handler (but in scope for the other functions shown). The problem here isn't scope. Also, using a click handler to decide which input is active won't work properly because the user might move around with the tab key.

Comment: try using latest or jquery version above 1.9 and use on() instead of the live() there

Answer (score 1):

The `local` variable masks `global` variable for the entire `function`.

To access the `global` `id`, you can use **`window.id`**.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Did you read the OP's code? There is only one `id` variable declared anywhere, and it's not global.